# What is the purpose of Delayed Branching?

Tags: cpu, computer-architecture

I study solutions of control hazards in a processor. One method is delayed branching. To my understanding, specific number of instructions (depending on pipeline length) are always executed subsequent to branch instruction and branch is taken later. What I don't get is, what if the instructions subsequent to the branch actually edits the registers related to the branch subroutine? Let me clarify:

```
 adds r1, r0, r2

 beq target_branch

 (subsequent instructions that edit r1)

 target_branch add r1, r1, r5

  ...
```

Comment: What happens will depend on the design. In the MIPS R2000, they simply execute. There are no interlocks or re-starts involved regarding 'stale' values, either. If you don't want the registers read stale or modified/written then you don't insert those instructions after the branch. Assembler tools (and compiler tools) existed that you could apply to catch and/or automatically modify the instruction stream at compile time. For processors that avoid stale reads using interlocks, they'd stall but still execute. It's possible to unwind, depending on depth.

Comment: Perhaps it has to do with pipeline synchronisation. If the instructions have different execution cycles, then it would go out of sync.

Comment: In the P II x86 processor, the instructions being executed are in the re-order buffer and each have their own result fields and source references. They can execute out of order, but the retire unit posts the result fields to the registers in-order. In a case like this, a delayed branch detection would pause the retire unit and optionally later flush the re-order buffer (or not), depending. It only takes a small imagination to come up with a number of interesting approaches. That's what's fun about CPU design.

Comment: As said, here you might find the answer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_pipelining

Comment: Another interesting area related to your question is VLIW, where each instruction may initiate multiple functional units on various tasks (multiple FP operations, for example.) The problem here is code generation. One may wish to move instructions after a branch to execute above the branch (filling available slots in the prior instructions) and then throw away results depending upon the actual branch result. See Dr. Ellis' Ph.D. thesis on the Bulldog compiler (circa 1985, or so.)

Comment: The question in the title is different from the question in the text. Which one are you asking?

Comment: the what if is either 1) the chip has a design bug or 2) the software has a bug.   in this case arm does not have branch shadow or branch delay slots like mips does or pretends to.   the instructions after the beq in arm which this code appears to be, do not execute the path goes from your beq to the add.

Comment: in primitive, textbook, etc designs, the delay slot or branch shadow or whatever demonstrates a way to save a clock on the flushing of the pipe.  software no longer needs to do that even in the mips cores I have used much less x86, arm, etc, as the logic takes care of branch prediction and reordering and parallel execution and other ways to deal with branches.

Comment: Understand that textbook is a textbook, it exposes you to the basic terminology and ideas that go into a pipelined processor, but no reason to assume that processors uses that depth nor those exact stages.  you can for sure, but dont have to design your core exactly that way.

Comment: to clarify it is a bug in the design or code if it does something bad.  per your specific question that would be 1) desirable (if this processor had a delay slot) because that is one way to use the delay slot to prep for the thing you are branching to 2) a software bug if it messes up a register you wanted to use as a parameter.   Just like any other bug thats on you.   It wouldnt be a chip bug as the chip would do what you told it, and if you told it to mess with a register it will.  Processors are incredibly dumb, they do what you tell them.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič I didn't mind to take a look at Wikipedia, actually it is nice article

Comment: @immibis I guess you are right. The question and the title don't conform each other. Sorry for that. I was a little confused at the time I was asking this.

Comment: @old_timer a clear explanation. Bugs in my head are flushed now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of delayed branching is maximising speed of code execution.

In early processors instructions were first fetched, one by one from memory.  Then they were decoded and finally executed.

The processor designers noticed that most of the time machine code is executed in a linear fashion.  It became clear that you could speed up typical code execution speed by introducing a pipeline to do these in parallel:

- On the first cycle you fetch the next instruction
- On the second cycle you fetch the second instruction an simultaneously decode the first.
- On the next cycle you execute the first instruction, decode the second and fetch the third.

From here on in because you are doing three things at once you are executing code faster.

This works fine until your code needs to branch.  At this point the designers had one of two choices to make, either

1. Flush the pipe and start again.  This has the advantage that code is easier to follow but does slow the code every time a branch or jump is taken.
2. Start fetching code from the new location but still execute any instructions in the pipe.  This is potentially faster if it is OK to execute instructions after the branch  but it is up to the programmer to decide and most if not all processors have a NOP instruction for use when it is not.

You don't have to worry about this if using a high level language as the compiler will take care of it for you but if you know what you are doing you may be able to squeeze out a little more performance in Assembler.

Note: Not all pipelines are 3 stage, you need to read the data sheet carefully.  This answer is also given in very broad terms a detailed answer would be **too broad** as there is a lot of variation in approaches to processor design,

Comment: You shouldn't randomly use the community wiki function. It's an outdated concept now that everyone can suggest edits to a post.

Comment: @pipe is there anything in the guidelines to back this up.  I posted this as a community wicki as I didn't feel it was detailed enough to stand alone as an answer bur I did think it was useful and too long to be a comment.